# C# EF - Share the same object on different connections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to get the same object on different connections? Or change variable in the object and after SaveChaings change the object of the other connection too?

For example, I open connection 1 and look for an object that has a string variable "OLD".

Now I open a new connection 2 and look for the same "NEW" object again (it will have another HashCode).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOsmO.jpg)

How do I change string "OLD" to "NEW" in object in connection 2 and object in connection 1 also be updated?

Comment: You're going to need to show us some code that better describes what you are trying to do. Remember, a variable (of reference type) just contains a reference to some object, and you can change what it refers to with simple assignment. A string variable can be initialized with a literal string, and be assigned from a method call and then be assigned the result of an EF query. It can refer to any string object (or be set to `null`)

Comment: Added an image of the code, showing that User2 didn't have variable updated after updating User1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.in the connection 2 re-read the record before using it (always)
2. implement tracking / notification for entity changes (id, property, value etc of the entity) outside of dbContext, then you can display the new values. However, it is better to read the record again anyway, then when saving, we will not update it a second time